# Concat two JSON string columns with PySpark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have two columns (StringType):

| JSON 1 | JSON 2 |
| --- | --- |
| {"key1":"value1"} | {"key2":"value2"} |
| {"key3":"value3"} | {"key4":"value4"} |

I need to concat these columns to have a **LIST** of JSON in the third column (also string), something like this:

| JSON 1 | JSON 2 | JSON 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"key1":"value1"} | {"key2":"value2"} | [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}] |
| {"key3":"value3"} | {"key4":"value4"} | [{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value4"}] |

Actually I solved the problem, but I don't think it's the best approach:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, concat_ws, lit

def concat_jsons(df: DataFrame, columns: list):
    df = df.withColumn(
        'JSON 3', concat_ws(',', *columns)
    )

    return df.withColumn(
        'JSON 3',
        concat(lit('['), col('JSON 3'), lit(']'))
    )
```

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: what is the data type of the columns?

Comment: Both columns JSON 1 and JSON 2 are string.

Comment: if by `list` you mean `array`, you could then just use the array function -- `array('json 1', 'json 2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data =[["""{"key1":"value1"}""", """{"key2":"value2"}"""], ["""{"key3":"value3"}""","""{"key4":"value4"}"""] ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF('JSON 1','JSON 2')

df.show()
+-----------------+-----------------+
|           JSON 1|           JSON 2|
+-----------------------------------+
|{"key1":"value1"}|{"key2":"value2"}|
|{"key3":"value3"}|{"key4":"value4"}|
+-----------------+-----------------+

def concat_jsons(df: DataFrame, columns: list):
...   return df.withColumn('JSON 3',array(*columns))

concat_jsons(df, ['JSON 1','JSON 2']).show()

+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|           JSON 1|           JSON 2|              JSON 3|
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|{"key1":"value1"}|{"key2":"value2"}|[{"key1":"value1"...|
|{"key3":"value3"}|{"key4":"value4"}|[{"key3":"value3"...|
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

if you want "JSON 3" to be for StringType, cast it to string

```
def concat_jsons(df: DataFrame, columns: list):
...   return df.withColumn('JSON 3',array(*columns).cast('string'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks bro!